# Microsoft Word 2007 - Force 'Word Count' to just count a specific part of document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

In Microsoft Word 2007, I'd like the 'Word Count' feature to just count the words/characters in a specific part of the document automatically.

**I know that if I highlight a specific section, it will count just the highlighted.**

But is there a way for it to count all the words in the document from a specific point on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have anything against placing the cursor at the desired location and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> and then just [looking in the status bar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA012303581033.aspx#2)?